# Within an equation, how would I put text directly above other text?

Tags: equations

I've seen something a little like this in a textbook I'm reading and I'm not sure how this would be written in LaTeX, can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what it means, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sincos}{\mathop{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}\sin\\\cos\end{array}\Big\}}}

\begin{document}

\[
Z = A \sincos k_1x \sincos k_1y \sincos ckt
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]